# Implementing nested subtotals

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Inserting a nested subtotal in a spreadsheet is a facility that Excel performs very well.
But if a subset of this facility can be implemented in MMA for a table which needs it the  hassle of its export/import will be avoided.
As an example I have the following 3-columns matrix, the first two columns of which I want subtotals values for. The matrix was sorted so that the rows I want subtotaled are grouped together:.

```
data = {{Pi, A, 15}, {Pi, B, 20}, {Pi, B, 10}, {Pi, C, 20}, {Pi/2, A, 
1}, {Pi/2, B, 2}, {Pi/2, B, 3}, {Pi/3, B, 10}}
```

And I want this result in separate matrix from the input data.

```
result = {{π, A, 15}, {π, B, 30}, {π, C, 20}, {π, 
"∑", 65}, {π/2, A, 1}, {π/2, B, 5}, {π/2, 
"∑", 6}, {π/3, B, 10}, {π/3, "∑", 
10}, {"∑", "∑", 81}} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I came up with a partial result,and what remains is too challenging for me (it is wrong  to group results only on breaks in column 2.)

```
{#[[1, 1]], "∑", Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ SplitBy[data, First] (* subtotals col1 *)
{ "∑", "∑", Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ {data} (*grand total *)
```

I would like to have a generalised answer, valid for more than two columns for subtotals as in the example I gave here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this as a start (currently very time poor):

```
fun[u_] := Module[{g, s1, sub}, g = GatherBy[u, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];
  s1 = GatherBy[{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ 
     g, #[[1]] &];
  sub = {Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ {#[[1, 1]], "\[CapitalSigma]", 
        Total[#[[All, 3]]]}} & /@ s1;
  (Join @@ Riffle[s1, sub])~
   Join~{Style[#, Blue, Bold] & /@ {"\[CapitalSigma]", 
      "\[CapitalSigma]", Total[u[[All, 3]]]}}
  ]
```

Applying:

```
fun[data] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

An interactive approach:

```
opn[u_] := 
 Module[{g, s1, sub, tot, sbt}, g = GatherBy[u, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];
  s1 = GatherBy[{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Total[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ 
     g, #[[1]] &];
  sub = MapThread[
    FlipView[{Grid@#1, Grid@#2}] &, {s1, GatherBy[u, #[[1]] &]}];
  tot = Style[#, Blue, Bold] & /@ {"\[CapitalSigma]", 
     "\[CapitalSigma]", Total[u[[All, 3]]]};
  sbt = {Style[#, Red, Bold] & /@ {#[[1, 1]], "\[CapitalSigma]", 
        Total[#[[All, 3]]]}} & /@ s1;
  Column[Join[Riffle[sub, Grid /@ sbt], {Grid[{tot}]}], Frame -> True]]
```

Applying:

```
opn[data]
```

[image]

I am not sure whether the generalization was meant to cover:  more data columns (i.e. same criteria but more columns to add, if so relatively easy to adapt); or desire to choose to vary and increase the collapse/expand of groups (ala Excel pivot tables)...this would be more complex...beyond my time (and skill)...

Comment: thanks for your extended and adaptive answer which made discover the usefulness of `FlipView`. I thought about partly emulating the Excel pivot tables but it is a question too presumptuous to ask by a modest MMA user as myself who may not thoroughly understand any answer received.

Comment: @SigismondKmiecik thank you...I just wanted to post something hopefully useful or motivating. We are all learners...the fun is playing with new approaches...good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
 Reap[(
      ( Sow[Append[#[[1, 1 ;; 2]], Total@Flatten@Take[#, All, {3}]]] & /@
                SplitBy[#, #[[2]] &] ; 
                Sow[{#[[1, 1]], "S", Total@Flatten@Take[#, All, {3}]}]) & /@ 
                 SplitBy[ data , #[[1]]  & ]); 
    Sow[{"Grand", "Tot", Total@Flatten@Take[data, All, {3}]}]][[2,1]]  // MatrixForm
```

[image]

With a little work work with `Nest` to generalize..

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, generalized to more "columns", so long as number of "columns" is consistent across lists:

```
nestedTotal[list_] := Module[{cnt = Length[list[[1]]]},
  NestWhileList[(cnt--; 
     Map[Append[#[[1, ;; cnt]], Total[#[[All, -1]]]] &, 
      GatherBy[#, #[[;; cnt]] &]]) &, list, cnt > 0 &]]

data = {{Pi, A, 15}, {Pi, B, 20}, {Pi, B, 10}, {Pi, C, 20}, {Pi/2, A, 
    1}, {Pi/2, B, 2}, {Pi/2, B, 3}, {Pi/3, B, 10}};

result = nestedTotal[data]

data = {{Pi, A, B, 15}, {Pi, A, B, 20}, {Pi, B, B, 10}, {Pi, A, C, 
    20}, {Pi/2, A, A, 1}, {Pi/2, A, B, 2}, {Pi/2, B, B, 3}, {Pi/3, A, 
    B, 10}};

result = nestedTotal[data]
```

Outputs:

[image]

and

[image]

You can "decorate" the results as desired (e.g., sigma symbol, etc.), e.g. like:

```
Join @@ Function[arg, 
    Map[PadLeft[#, Length[arg[[1, 1]]], "\[Sum]"] &, Rest[arg], {2}]][
   result] // MatrixForm
```

or this, which gives precisely the output of your OP (I have not extensively exercised this,  can probably be simplified, in any case, massaging results is pretty trival):

```
Join @@ GatherBy[
   Join @@ MapIndexed[
     Function[{arg, idx}, 
      Map[Flatten@
         Insert[#, ConstantArray["\[Sum]", idx - 1], Length[#]] &, 
       arg]], Rest@result], First] // MatrixForm
```